# Quickly Build Package Repeatedly in R

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have a package I'm writing in R that has a boatload of complicated C++ code which takes a while to compile.

When I change the code, I'd like to quickly rebuild the package so I can test it. However, `R CMD build` seems to start from scratch each time, rather than using my code's makefiles to do only what is needed.

Is there a way to quickly do repeated builds of a package in R for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dirk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45512708/752843) above pointed me in the right direction, but was insufficient. Since he has requested that I not append the final steps I required, I do so here.
My question could not have been answered without the following.

Dirk's answer did not work off the bat for me. If compilation still seems slow to you, try running:

```
ccache -s
```

The result will look a little like this

```
cache directory                     /home/myuser/.ccache
primary config                      /home/myuser/.ccache/ccache.conf
secondary config      (readonly)    /etc/ccache.conf
cache hit (direct)                     0
cache hit (preprocessed)               0
cache miss                           989
cache hit rate                         0 %
called for link                       12
preprocessor error                    12
cleanups performed                    16
files in cache                       177
cache size                          31.1 MB
max cache size                       5.0 GB
Note that cache isn't getting hit, which means ccache isn't doing anything.
```

You can use:

```
export CCACHE_LOGFILE=ccache.log
R CMD build .
```

to do some debugging, though this wasn't helpful for me.

What fixed things was to run:

```
export CCACHE_NOHASHDIR=true
R CMD build .
```

As it turns out, ccache sometimes takes the location of a file into account. R CMD build . appears to build in a temporary directory, so the location of the files was changing each time.

Comment: This is answer is incorrect / inapplicable as it is caused by a lack of understanding of the proper build process.  As the R documentation clearly states, standard build process is to first create a .tar.gz and then (after an optional check) install from the tarball via `R CMD INSTALL pkg_1.2-3.tar.gz`.  Or, during development, install run `R CMD INSTALL .` from the directory.  `R CMD build` is simply wrong.

Comment: The above comment focuses on a unimportant aspect of the answer, and fails to mention that `R CMD build` produces the tarball in question providing immediate feedback on ability to compile without undesired installation.

Comment: Dirk: It describes what was necessary for me. I wish it had Just Worked the way you say it should, but it didn't. It seems our development environments are different.

Comment: `cd ..; R CMD build mydir/; R CMD check mydir_1.2-3.tar.gz;  R CMD INSTALL mydir_1.2-3.tar.gz` is the *documented* and *recommended* workflow which always uses `ccache` for me.  As does `R CMD INSTALL .`.

Answer (score 4):

I am a little overdue a short blog post on this, but I mentioned it a couple of times before:  use [ccache](https://ccache.samba.org/). It helps dramatically when the files don't change (ie when you just alter help pages), or when few files changes.  Caching is a very clever trick, and package is robust.

On Ubuntu/Debian:  `sudo apt-get install ccache` followed by e.g. this in your `~/.R/Makevars`:

```
VER=
CCACHE=ccache
#CCACHE=
CC=$(CCACHE) gcc$(VER)
CXX=$(CCACHE) g++$(VER)
CXX11=$(CCACHE) g++$(VER)
CXX14=$(CCACHE) g++$(VER)
```

That also allows to switch between `g++` versions. Changing it to `clang++` is left as an exercise to the reader ;-)

Besides this, see the options to `R CMD build` and `R CMD INSTALL` to skip vignette and/or manual building to further speed up re-builds.

Illustration:  Here is re-install of Rcpp itself (fresh from a `git pull`) where the first installation takes 21.9 seconds on my (decent) machine at work, the second then only takes 1.4 seconds thanks to `ccache`:

```
~/git/rcpp(master)$ time R CMD INSTALL .
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
** libs
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wextra -Wno-empty-body -Wno-unused -c Date.cpp -o Date.o
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wextra -Wno-empty-body -Wno-unused -c Module.cpp -o Module.o
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wextra -Wno-empty-body -Wno-unused -c Rcpp_init.cpp -o Rcpp_init.o
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wextra -Wno-empty-body -Wno-unused -c api.cpp -o api.o
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wextra -Wno-empty-body -Wno-unused -c attributes.cpp -o attributes.o
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wextra -Wno-empty-body -Wno-unused -c barrier.cpp -o barrier.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o Rcpp.so Date.o Module.o Rcpp_init.o api.o attributes.o barrier.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (Rcpp)

real    0m21.917s
user    0m21.388s
sys     0m2.304s
~/git/rcpp(master)$ ./cleanup 
~/git/rcpp(master)$ time R CMD INSTALL .
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
** libs
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wextra -Wno-empty-body -Wno-unused -c Date.cpp -o Date.o
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wextra -Wno-empty-body -Wno-unused -c Module.cpp -o Module.o
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wextra -Wno-empty-body -Wno-unused -c Rcpp_init.cpp -o Rcpp_init.o
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wextra -Wno-empty-body -Wno-unused -c api.cpp -o api.o
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wextra -Wno-empty-body -Wno-unused -c attributes.cpp -o attributes.o
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wextra -Wno-empty-body -Wno-unused -c barrier.cpp -o barrier.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o Rcpp.so Date.o Module.o Rcpp_init.o api.o attributes.o barrier.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (Rcpp)

real    0m1.444s
user    0m1.380s
sys     0m1.452s
~/git/rcpp(master)$
```

*Edit a few years later:*  I did [write that blog post](https://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2017/11/27/), and it contains another important nugget. One really needs a file `~/.ccache/ccache.conf` because a) R unpacks files freshly (so 'newer `ctime`) and puts them into temp. directories. So when working with `R CMD INSTALL somepkg_1.2.3.tar.gz` (as opposed to just sources) this helps:

```
max_size = 5.0G
# important for R CMD INSTALL *.tar.gz as tarballs are expanded freshly -> fresh ctime
sloppiness = include_file_ctime
# also important as the (temp.) directory name will differ
hash_dir = false
```

Comment: I stand by what I wrote, and showed: 21 secs down to 1.5 secs. I have been using `ccache` on multiple machines for probably a decade or so.

Comment: Do not edit my posts without asking. I am removing your edit in a few minutes.

Comment: My apologies. Without the edit the answer is, from my point of view, useful but incomplete. Therefore, although I have upvoted it, I cannot accept it.